# Can vowpal wabbit use all my CPU cores?

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I've tried to train --oaa vowpal wabbit classifier on 10M+ train data and found that it uses only one core. Is any ways to make it use all 12 cores?

Answer (score 4):

VW uses two threads: one for loading&parsing the input data and one for the machine learning.
VW comes with a [spanning_tree](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Cluster_parallel.pdf) tool for parallel execution (AllReduce) of several VW instances on a cluster (e.g. Hadoop) or on a single machine (`--span_server localhost`).

That said, I think 12 cores are not enough for AllReduce to pay off. For the best results, you need to do hyper-parameter search anyway, so you can do it in parallel using the 12 cores.

Comment: You may also want to avoid `--audit` which may otherwise slow you orders of magnitude depending on the speed of your disks.